# An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle11g

i have a serious problem with my code, an exception is always thrown when i try to retreive ID (number) from table (correspondant)

```
        private void comboboxCorrespondant_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        #region connectDB

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        #endregion
        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT ID FROM CORRESPONDANT WHERE desingation = " + comboboxCorrespondant.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        object _id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        string returnId = _id.ToString();

        IdtextBox.Text = "";
        if (_id != null)
        {
            IdtextBox.Text = returnId;
        }

        con.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like [tag:C] to me.

Comment: THIS WAS  a typing error, edited : C#